# Condition on two distributions. All N(0,1).

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This problem

> The RV $X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$ are independent $N(0,1)$. Consider $Y_1=X_2+X_3, Y_2=X_1+X_3,Y_3=X_1+X_2$. Find the conditional density of $Y_1$ given $Y_2=Y_3=0$

(From Gut An intermediate course in probability Ch5p16.)

I wrote up matrix A where AX=Y. From $AA'$ I can then find the relevant variances I need in the density functions.

It made me realize I don't know how to take "double" condition. I know $$f_{A \mid B}=\frac{f_{A , B}}{f_B}$$ But then is 
$$f_{A \mid (B,C)}=f_{(A \mid B) \mid C}=\frac{ \frac{f_{A , B,C}}{f_{B,C}} }{f_C} (1)$$

If I were just to apply the defn traight on I thinkI would get $f_{A \mid (B,C)} = \frac{f_{A , B,C}}{f_{B,C}} (2)$.

I can find A,B,C and B,C bu the formula for multivariable NF. I wonder if (1) or (2) is the right formula, I think (2) is. Then I'll try to divide the densities - unless there's a smarter way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional distributions are not even needed, one can simply compute the density $f_Y$ of $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)'$ then the conditional density of $Y_1$ conditionally on $Y_2=Y_3=0$ is proportional to $f_Y(\ ,0,0)$.

In the present case, $Y$ is centered with covariance $$C=AA'=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2\end{pmatrix},$$ hence $$C^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\color{red}{3/4}&-1/4&-1/4\\-1/4&3/4&-1/4\\-1/4&-1/4&3/4\end{pmatrix},$$ and one knows that $$f_Y(y_1,y_2,y_3)\propto\exp\left(-\frac12y_1^2(C^{-1})_{1,1}+\cdots\right),$$ where $\cdots$ is a linear combination of $y_2^2$, $y_3^2$, and $y_iy_j$ for $i\ne j$. All these are zero when $y_2=y_3=0$ hence one is left with a conditional density proportional to $$\exp\left(-\frac12y_1^2(C^{-1})_{1,1}\right)=\exp\left(-\frac12\frac{y_1^2}{\color{red}{4/3}}\right),$$ and surely you can fully identify the conditional density from there.

Comment: "is proportional to $f_Y(\ ,0,0)$." Why is that?

Comment: Definition--see you own post.

Comment: Is it proportional because Y is a linear combination of X?

Comment: No, it is proportional because the density of $Z$ conditional on $T=t$ is $f_{Z,T}(\ ,t)/f_T(t)$, which is, once $t$ is fixed, proportional to the function $f_{Z,T}(\ ,t):z\mapsto f_{Z,T}(z,t)$. Here $Z=Y_1$, $T=(Y_2,Y_3)$ and $t=(0,0)$.

Comment: So It basically follows from the multivariate NormPDF. 

I read the book and solved in a way very similar to this, by using theorem 5.1 in Gut. 

Your way is actually faster since you ignore the 1/(sigma*sqrt(2 pi)) and just say "it's proportional".

Answer (score 1):

The notation $f_{(A\mid B)\mid C}$ makes no sense.  There is only ever one divider, which is placed between the outcome events and the given condition.  It denotes that we are measuring over a partition of the domain.

What you want is:

$$\begin{align}
f_{A\mid B,C} & = \frac{f_{A,B\mid C} }{ f_{B\mid C} }
\\[1ex] & = \frac{f_{A,B,C}/f_C}{f_{B,C}/f_C}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{f_{A,B,C}}{f_{B,C}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why use `\large` and `\Large`? The result is ugly...